# Realizar parse de dados de um banco C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, desserialização

Preciso *deserializar* as informações de um banco de dados em `C#`, tenho a seguinte `SQL` em `C#`:

```
select 
      Id, 
      Email, 
      Name, 
      Login 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE Login = @login
      and Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', @password) ,2)
```

E para *deserializar* estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    toReturn.Id = int.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString());
    toReturn.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
    toReturn.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    toReturn.UserName = reader["Login"].ToString();
}
```

Porém, nunca retorna valor algum e não joga nenhuma exception. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Fazendo a query desta forma:

```
select 
      Id, 
      Email, 
      Name, 
      Login 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE Login = 'usuario'
      and Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', '123') ,2)
```

Ela retorna o usuário correto.

Para executar, estou utilizando este código:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Email, Name, Login FROM [vw_usuarios] WHERE 
Login = '@login' and Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', '@password') ,2)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

**Observações:**

- Já testei no banco de dados e funcionou.
- Quando removo os parâmetros, ele retorna todos os valores.

Comment: Que parâmetros que remove? Aparentemente o problema está em como manda a *query*, mas você não postou essa parte.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Os valores de `username` e `password` no momento desta execução está como? Note que no DB está fazendo na tabela, e no C# está fazendo na *view*, isso pode dar diferença

Comment: estão preenchidos com os valores que estão no banco. 'username' e '123'. Quando eu deixo de usar os parâmetros e concateno com a query funciona, mas gostaria de usar com os parâmetros.

Comment: Na sua query está diferente, então o problema deve ser este, parece não ser um erro de programação e sim de confusão dos dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ***erro*** está como está enviada a informação no parâmetro, ele não precisa de aspas simples na `SQL`, está assim:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Email, Name, Login FROM [vw_usuarios] WHERE
 Login = '@login' and Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', '@password') ,2)";
```

**mude para**:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Email, Name, Login FROM [vw_usuarios] WHERE
 Login = @login and Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', @password) ,2)";
```

---

***Qual é a diferença:***

A remoção das aspas simples nos `@login` e `@password` não precisa, o próprio `Parameters` se encarrega de colocar as aspas tendo em mente que os dados são dois textos.

***Código completo e corrigido:***

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Email, Name, Login FROM [vw_usuarios] WHERE 
        Login = @login and
        Senha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), HASHBYTES('MD5', @password) ,2)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    toReturn.Id = int.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString());
    toReturn.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
    toReturn.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    toReturn.UserName = reader["Login"].ToString();
}
```

***Dica:*** nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) tem um exemplo que você pode perceber a diferença.

---

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Difference with Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155004/difference-with-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)
- [Propriedade SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)